# Handlebars equivalent of Smarty's strip modifier

Tags: handlebars.js

Is there built-in helper/utility in Handlebars template system that will allow me to strip newline/tab etc. characters off the string (equivalent of [Smarty's strip variable modifier](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.modifier.strip.tpl))? Or do I have to write and register my own helper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no strict equivalent builtin to Smarty's strip, but Handlebars have [whitespace control](http://handlebarsjs.com/expressions.html#whitespace-control) operator tilda `~`. Otherwise try to implement [block helper](http://handlebarsjs.com/block_helpers.html) by yourself.

Comment: Yes. I had to write my own helper using `String.protorype.trim()`.